# ¿Por qué no entra en este "if"?

Tags: python, condiciones

estoy tratando de hacer unos ejercicios con el condicional IF.

No sé por qué siempre me saltan las dos lineas de print:

```
print("Bienvenido/a, adivina un numero de entre el 0 y el 25")
azar = input("¿Cual crees que es el número de la suerte?")

if azar == "12":
    print("Felicidades, lo has acetado")

print("Este no es el número")
```

La cosa es que, incluso he vuelto a las explicaciones y se supone que está bien encadenado ¿Hay algo que este haciendo mal o me este saltando?

Comment: Bienvenido, si mal no entiendo lo que te molesta es que al final imprime el texto `Este no es el número` si es así, le falta un bloque de `else` a tu condición.

Comment: Si no conoces la sentencia `else` sino sólo `if`, puedes usar otro `if` delante del segundo print, con la condición contraria al primero. Es decir `if azar != '12': print("Este no es el número")`. De ese modo o se ejecuta el primero, o el segundo, y nunca los dos. En el fondo eso es lo que hace `else`.

Comment: si tienes una nueva pregunta, haz una nueva publicación. La pregunta actual ya fue respondida

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El `if` no funciona por que el código `print("Este no es el número")` está fuera del contexto del bloque condicional, se encuentra en el bloque principal. En Python para identificar que un bloque de código se encuentra dentro de una condición debe estar [indentada](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentaci%C3%B3n).

Ejemplo:

```
a = 0
if a > 0:
    # éste código se encuentra dentro del bloque condicional
    print ('a es mayor a cero')

# éste es el bloque principal
print('estoy en el bloque principal')
```

Simplemente falta que agregues `else` a tu bloque de código condicional, el cual será ejecutado cuando no se cumpla la condición `if azar == "12"`, es decir, cuando el valor ingresado sea diferente a 12.

```
print("Bienvenido/a, adivina un numero de entre el 0 y el 25")
azar = input("¿Cual crees que es el número de la suerte?")

if azar == "12":
    print("Felicidades, lo has acetado")
else:
    print("Este no es el número")
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la explicación!! Donde estoy recibiendo las clases no me lo explicaron **if/else.** Me explicaron **"if" y "or"** y me estaba comiendo la cabeza con ello ¿Con el "or" se podría hacer algo similar?

Comment: `or` es el opuesto a `and`, `else` va con `if`, no se usa en comparaciones como `and` y `or`

Answer (score 0):

Lo que te falla es que, acierte el if o no, el segundo print siempre lo va a ejecutar. La solución es poner un if/else en vez de un simple if.

```
print("Bienvenido/a, adivina un numero de entre el 0 y el 25")
azar = input("¿Cual crees que es el número de la suerte?")

if azar == "12":
    print("Felicidades, lo has acetado")

else:
    print("Este no es el número")
```